# How to terminate scanf after a few seconds?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I'm using signals in C language. The program consists in wait a few seconds for a user keyboard input if the time ends, the program terminates. However, I always have to enter text although time was over if not the program never ends. Is there any way to avoid scanf?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NSECS 10
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
# define BELLS "\007\007\007"

int alarm_flag = FALSE;

void bye(){
    printf("Good bye...");
}

void setflag(){
    alarm_flag = TRUE;
}

int main() {
char name[20];
    do {
        

        printf("File name: \n"); 
        scanf("%s", name);

        signal(SIGALRM, setflag);
        alarm(NSECS);
        
        if (alarm_flag == TRUE){
            printf(BELLS);
            atexit(adios); 
            return 0;
        } // if the user enters a file name, the program continues
```

Comment: Please add an OS tag.

Comment: @Joshua: I’m not sure there is an appropriate tag—Unix-like?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: There is a posix tag, or he could just put the tag for the OS he's actually using.

Comment: @Joshua now is up to date, thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there—set the alarm first, and call `scanf` afterwards. The signal will interrupt the call to `read()` inside `scanf()`, which causes `scanf()` to return immediately.

```
volatile int alarm_flag = 0;
void setflag(int sig) {
    alarm_flag = 1;
}

...

struct sigaction act = {};
act.sa_handler = set_flag;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);

...

    alarm(NSECS);
    scanf("%s", name);
    if (alarm_flag) {
        ...
```

A couple notes:

- `alarm_flag` should be `volatile`.
- `setflag` should take one `int` parameter.
- Declare your functions as `func(void)` not `func()`. Declaring a function as `func()` is an old-fashioned style from before 1990 or so and there is no benefit to using it today. (Note that C++ is different.)

More notes:

- You should not use `== TRUE` or `== FALSE`. In this particular case it may work fine, but there are cases where it doesn’t. So I would almost never use `== TRUE`.
- As an exercise this code with `alarm` is reasonable, but if you want to do this kind of thing in a production application you would probably use something like `libuv` instead of `alarm()`. It’s not that there’s something *wrong* with this approach, just that using non-blocking IO and `libuv` would probably be easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution has worked very well for me

Comment: Pedantic: type of `alarm_flag` should `sig_atomic_t`.